# Is it possible to granularly configure OSX's application level firewall?

Tags: macos, firewall

From looking at the UI in the System Preferences App, it looks like the application firewall rules in OSX's firewall are "all or nothing" -- "Allow all" or "Block all" effectively. I'm under the impression that this UI is ultimately editing `com.apple.alf.plist` behind the scenes.

Is there a way, perhaps by editing that plist, to get more granular rules? (like "only allow connections from this range of IP addresses, etc.")

Comment: ### ALF or PF? If you need to roll your own firewall solution and settings, you have to distinguish between PF and ALF. Do you need to block inbound or outbound connections based on IPs, Port and IP protocol? Or do you need to block network communication for specific applications? In the first case, you will be using **OpenBSD's PF**, and in the latter **ALF**. To block by IP range, it's more likely that you'll be using PF, in which case you can use the advanced settings in the free IceFloor app to change configurations. *Note: LittleSnitch is a commercial software and not free.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a third party firewall application like LittleSnitch or NoobProof?

LittleSnitch: http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html
NoobProof: http://www.hanynet.com/noobproof/

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, though.